# Telerik TxtformatProvider not found

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

Simple question - I am trying to use the txtformatprovider for plain text import/export on the telerik richtextbox, however I am unable to reference the correct assembly.

I have added Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders and Telerik.Windows.Documents and referenced them, but it is still not working.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Have solved the problem?

Comment: No, sorry I did not make my question clear in the beginning.  I have always had the rich text box working, but it is the exporting/importing that I needed help on.  I was reading the article from telerik but I couldn't get the plain text format provider working, so i asked if anyone else used it before...

Comment: Thanks for the help though...  I will accept your answer anyway since I didnt make my question clear in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

To get all the features of the richTextBox available you should reference the following assemblies:

Telerik.Windows.Controls,
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input,
Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation,
Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView,
Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.

Comment: I do have those assemblies to make my RTB work - the problem is I now want to import/export my content to a database using format providers ([link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/richtextbox-features-import-export-import-export.html)), but I cant get the plain txt formatprovider to work...

Comment: This is not what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

To import or export add the reference `Telerik.Windows.Documents` to the project and the namespace `using Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Txt;` to the code.